# Runtime of traversal over LinkedList vs ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I'm getting strange results in a rather simple piece of code.
Here is the code in question:

```
    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(6200000);
    List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6200000; i++)
    {
        arrayList.add(i);
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6200000; i++)
    {
        linkedList.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

Now, here is the problem:
When size is given as argument to ArrayList CTOR, as in 
**"new ArrayList(6200000)"**, the printed value is always greater than 2000.
When size is not given to ArrayList CTOR, as in 
**"new ArrayList()"**, the printed value is 1000 or a bit over 1000.
The thing is that multiple executions give different values, but my point is that there is a significant difference between the two described scenarios, and I just don't understand why.
how the way the ArrayList is constructed affects the code related to the LinkedList?
Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Creating bad benchmarks can give confusing results.

Answer (score 1):

When you add nodes to a LinkedList you are create a lot of objects (two per value) so you will be stressing the memory allocator.  When you create a very large data structure like you are in the first instance you will be focusing the memory sizes to grow. In the case of `new ArrayList()` you are focusing to grow the most as the ArrayList has to resize many times, most like resulting in a larger Eden size speeding up short lived objects.  I would watch what the heap sizes are doing while you run this test to see how the memory grows differently.